# Why memory leaks occurs when using DataStore API on dev server (not tested in production)?

Tags: google-app-engine, memory-leaks, google-cloud-datastore

Could guys please help me find what causes memory leak ? It drives me crazy :(((

I'm using GAE SDK 1.6.1. I created sample project with single servlet that contains following doGet method

```
protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException
{
    {
        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

        System.out.println();
        for (long i = 1; i <= 10000000; ++i)
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity("Visitor");
            entity.setProperty("name", "Name is " + i);
            entity.setProperty("value", "Value is " + i);
            Key key = datastore.put(entity);
            System.out.println(key.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Call to this servlet fails with OutOfMemory exception because all temporary datastore objects remain in the memory.

Here is tree of incoming references to held object obtained using YourKit Java Profiler.

[image]

Does anybody know why? How can I avoid this? Is it GAE-specific bug or something in my development environment?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, it answers your question.

Comment: Does this happen on the dev_appserver, or in production?

Comment: It happens on dev_appserver. I'm not sure about production. I just uploaded it to `http://alphahuber.appspot.com/test` and it throws `DeadlineExceededException` before it runs out of memory. But on the other hand I don't know how big heap is on GAE instance.

Comment: Hey @NickJohnson, could you suggest workaround besides raising JVM heap size ? Thanks!

Comment: @ruslan Upload less data? I'm afraid there's not much getting around the in-memory nature of the datastore stub, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/e8c5d4947bc61593?pli=1) thread where Ikai Lan (Google) says *"The development server datastore stub is an in memory Map that is persisted to disk".*

Perhaps it answers my question.