# Datastore access is horribly slow on dev server if you have more than few objects in it

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing, google-cloud-datastore, software-design

This question is continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843975/why-memory-leaks-occurs-when-using-datastore-api-on-dev-server-not-tested-in-pr) I asked earlier.

How do you guys test your project on dev server if you need to have more than few objects in Datastore ?

The fact that GAE SDK for Java keeps Datastore in memory is just killing me. I can't produce reliable code if I can't test it on my machine. I wonder how other engineers deal with it.

Currently I have to preload data in backend instance servlet from `.bin` file which I drop into `WEB-INF\`.

Then I test some code in [DeferredTask](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask.html). Following line of code (using Objectify)

```
List<AnonAnswer> answers = dao.ofy().query(AnonAnswer.class).ancestor(visitor).list();
```

takes 1.5 **seconds** to run where `AnonAnswer` is as simple as

```
public class AnonAnswer extends Answer implements Serializable {
    @Parent Key<Visitor> parent;

    public AnonAnswer() {
    }

    public Key<Visitor> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Key<Visitor> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

and I have 2K Visitor and ~60K AnonAnswer objects. `local_db.bin` is mere 49MB. Why is it slow ? It works instantly (as I expect it) in production (~3M Visitors as of now).

I'm ready to spend some time and write something like [gae-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/gae-sqlite/) but I don't have file-write access in Java version of GAE SDK. I don't know why it works in Python version.

I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the App Engine dev server seems to use some kind of HashMap to store objects, I would guess that there's some kind of hashing performed on the Protocol Buffer bytes or the original object of the Key  - are these likely to be similar between objects (ie. the id, the parent and the kind) if so then you might end up with too many clashes between objects.

Alternatively, Google might have set a default value for the size of the map making it too small for data sets of your size.

Comment: In the alternative above, a possible hack would be to manually change the size by editing the loadfactor of the hash map in the local_db.bin file when the server is not running? Very hacky and might not work at all.