# Memory usage while parsing XML file into Google App Engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-management, memory-leaks, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to parse a big (5GB) XML file (product catalog) into a google datastore. The issue I am having is it taking up a lot of memory. I was able to get the memory down from the parsing part by reading it line by line and deleting elements as I go. However something is still sticking behind.

My code is http://pastebin.com/ESARQikC

I believe the issue is occuring in this specific function

```
def process_element(self,item):
    if item.tag == "programname":
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'name':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)        
    elif item.tag == 'description':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'sku':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'manufacturer':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'price':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'buyurl':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'imageurl':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag == 'advertisercategory':
        self.Plist.append(item.text)
    elif item.tag=="product":
        Product(
            programname=("%s" % self.Plist[0]),
            name=("%s" % self.Plist[1]),
            description=("%s" % self.Plist[2][0:500]),
            sku=("%s" % self.Plist[3]),
            manufacturer=("%s" % self.Plist[4]),
            price=("%s" % self.Plist[5]),
            buyurl=("%s" % self.Plist[6]),
            imageurl=("%s" % self.getBigImageUrl(self.Plist[7])),
            advertisercategory=("%s" % self.Plist[8])).put()

        self.count+=1
        print self.count
        if self.count%15000 == 0:      
            time.sleep(10000)
        for ob in self.Plist:
            del ob
        del self.Plist
        self.Plist=[]
    del item
```

When I comment out the Product().put() line and run it, it can go through tons of lines without making much of a memory impact. The reason I added the sleep in the middle of it is I was thinking some subprocesses that GAE spawns were adding the data to the datastore and might need some time to operate. So I waited after adding 15000 items to see if any ram would be freed up (purged memory on the OS side as well) however it did not help. Is this something in my code or something I can't change related to adding data to a datastore. I'm stuck and confused after hours/days of playing around with it.

Comment: Hmmm, Nothing jumps out of me from looking at the code. I might have a play with it locally and see if I can come up with something. In terms of iterating through a file without using loads of memory you should use the built in generator expression.

Comment: call gc.collect() outside the process_element() this will force garbage collection.  Your other alternative is to run this process on your dev box, connected to the prod gae via remote_api, then you can use as much memory as have. Not sure why you need the sleep.   Also no need to do the `del ob` in the loop. Just a assigning the Plist to a new list removes all the references.  Again calling gc.collect() will force garbage collection.    Remember python uses reference counting so if you have anything referring to items in Plist outside of the process_element then gc won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this code in your development server?  There is a known problem with the dev server's datastore using up memory: [Why memory leaks occurs when using DataStore API on dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8843975/584846).  The reason is that it uses a memory map to store all of your entities.

Comment: Yea I am trying it on the dev server. Someone pointed me in the direction of https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce so I might give this a try too.